# Why regex validation is not working when i pass pattern from variable?

Tags: javascript

I have to validate the name using regex pattern but when I use pattern directly to match it's working and if I pass pattern from another variable it's not working

Working

```
new RegExp(/\.\./g) 
name.match(/\.\./g)
```

For example, if the name is'.test..csv' it should print not valid in the console. but it's not working if i use like this

```
var b= '/\.\./g';
var c =new RegExp(b)
```

```js
var name ='.test..csv';
var b= '/\.\./g';

//var c =new RegExp(/\.\./g);
var c =new RegExp(b);
console.log("c",c)


if(name.match(c)){
    console.log("Not valid")
}else{
    console.log("valid")
}
```

someone help me here

Comment: Start your basic debugging with `console.log(b)`

Comment: `/\.\./g` is not the same as `'/\.\./g'`; the first is a regular expression literal the second is a string. You can use a string as the first argument of `new RegExp()` but then you have to modify it. [More on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get a RegExp through a string do this:

```
var r = new RegExp("[content of regexp]","g") //e.g. "test#." not "/test#./g"
```

and remember that in js "\.\." will be converted to "..", so you should do this:

```js
var name ='.test..csv';

var c =new RegExp("\\.\\.","g");
console.log("c",c)


if(name.match(c)){
    console.log("Not valid")
}else{
    console.log("valid")
}
```

Comment: You are "forcing" the code to do as you expect but that is not actually the issue of the OP; the problem of the OP is caused by the fact the he passes two different arguments to `new RegExp()` thinking they are the same but `new RegExp(/\.\./g)` is not the same as `new RegExp('/\.\./g')`.

Comment: @secan Is it better now?

Comment: If you ask _me_, I'd say "not really" as the scenario mentioned by the OP requires the argument of `new RegExp()` to be a variable. Furthermore the question was why one case works and the other doesn't; the answer to that is somehow _implied_ in your post but you are not directly answering it. But that is just my opinion.

Comment: @secan Please feel free to edit my answer.